# use service property inside routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am trying send service property `catId` with templateUrl request inside route

i have service **formAction**

```
myApp.factory('formAction', [function () {

    var catId

    return {
        catId: catId,
    }
}]);
```

**route.js**

```
function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/ad/step1', {
                templateUrl: '/ad/place/step-one',
                controller : 'Step1Controller'

            }).when('/ad/step2', {
                templateUrl: function () {
                    // i dont want pass catId as parametr
                    return '/ad/place/step-two?catId=' // formAction.catId. 
                },
                controller : 'Step2Controller',
            }).otherwise({
                templateUrl: '/ad/place/step-one',
                controller : 'Step1Controller'
            });
        }
```

when i go step2 it must be send `catId` with request

*note*: i dont want pass `catId` in route as parametr like:

```
        templateUrl: function (param) {
            return '/ad/place/step-two?catId=' + param.catId. 
        },
```

is there way i can do it?

Comment: So, you just need to pass your `catId` value to 'Step2Controller'?

Comment: no, i need send `catId` as parametr of template request

Comment: Seems like a design flaw in your app. Why do you need to send GET param for template in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

So, as you're using the default (standard) angular routing, then we go to [$routeProvider documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) where we can see the following:

> **templateUrl** – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters: 
>   `{Array.<Object>}` - route parameters extracted from the current
>   `$location.path()` by applying the current route

Therefore, **the parameters coming to templateUrl are fixed**

It means that you can't inject your services into this function.

However, if you're using [angular UI router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) (best angular routing module IMHO), then you can find that each state has an optional parameter 'templateProvider' which is a **function that can be injected**.

Hope it will help.